# Compare two dates wih adding days to one in PHP

Tags: php, date, diff

My code:

```
<?php 
$today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$expire1 = $row['datetime'];
$dni_uslugi = $usluga_wybor['days'];
$expire = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($expire1. '+ '.$dni_uslugi.' days'));
$format = "Y-m-d H:i:s";
$date1  = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $today);
$date2  = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $expire);

if($date2 < $date1) echo 'delete';
```

It runs good for almost all dates... I have problem with few dates for example:
I have date 2016-03-07 22:32:54 and `$dni_uslug` for this date is 30 days so it should end at 7 april. It couldn't be deleted because it's active of course, but the code says delete for this date...

Any idea why the code do this? It plays good with almost 98% dates, but in few cases it works

Comment: *"I have date 2016-03-07 22:32:54 and $dni_uslug for this date is 30 days so it should end at 7 april"*. This year March has 31 days, as usual. 30 days after the 7th of March is April 6. If you need to add 1 month then add 1 month, not 30 days.

Comment: I would create the `DateTime` objects earlier in the code then use [`DateTime::add()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) to avoid the fuzziness of the formats accepted by [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). Something like `$date1=new DateTime(); $date2=(new($row['datetime']))->add(new DateInterval('P'.$dni_uslugi.'D'));`

Comment: @axiac it's not the point of my problem I need to add 30 day or 14 days or 7 days. It depends on service

Answer (score 0):

According to this code, adding 30 days gets you to Apr 6th.

```
<?php
$date1 = new DateTime('2016-03-07 22:32:54');
$date2 = clone($date1);
$daysToAdd = 30;
$date2->add(new DateInterval("P{$daysToAdd}D"));
echo "date1:" . $date1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
echo "date2:" . $date2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";

if($date2 < $date1) echo "delete\n";
else echo "keep\n";
```

Output:

```
date1:2016-03-07 22:32:54
date2:2016-04-06 22:32:54
keep
```

Comment: okay, my bad... however it's not my problem. I want ot know why script tells me the use date is expired if I add 30 days to 7 march... It should tell me that it's active until 6 april???